# How to write a Junit test for a method that takes a file path and creates a new file?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have method in Java class that takes a file path and creates a new file. How do I write a Junit test for this method?

```
public String sendToECM(String filePath) {
    String ecmDocId = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            DocumentPropertiesVO documentPropertiesVO = UploadFileToContentManagement.uploadDocument(file);
            ecmDocId = documentPropertiesVO.getDocumentID();
        }
        return ecmDocId;
    } catch (SomeException cee) {
        log.error("There was an error adding the document", cee);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the idea should be to create a test file, check whether it exists, remove it and assert whether it existed.

Comment: Verify that the file exists and that the content is the content you expect

Comment: Are you sure this method creates a new file?  It looks to me like it only does anything if the file already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Test
void testValidFilePath() {
  String filePath = "path.txt";
  String str = sendToECM(filePath);
  Assertions.assertNotEquals(str, ""); // or null, depending on what your StringUtils.EMPTY is doing

@Test
void testInvalidFilePath() {
  String filePath = "invalidPath.txt";
  String str = sendtoECM(filePath);
  Assertions.assertEquals(str, StringUtils.EMPTY);
```